# what is the max charge current of BQ2057?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have gone through the datasheet of this single cell Li-ion charge IC [BQ2057](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2057w.pdf)
but I couldn't find the charge current detail

Comment: It is determined by \$R_{SNS}\$, a value *you* choose and therefore you don't find the max charge current in the datasheet.

Comment: can I get 1A charge current from this IC?

Comment: The BQ2057 is only a controller, therefore there is no "charge current".
See the exemplary application circuit in the datasheet.
The maximum charge current is determined through the current capability of your power transistor and the sense resistor \$R_{SNS}\$

Comment: No. Because the IC doesn't *provide* the current, but the IC *controls* the current.

Comment: @querty: Please include links to datasheets when asking. Make it easy for those you are asking to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The available charge current is determined by the capability of the outboard transistor and the CC output current.

The applications section of the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2057.pdf) has typical charge circuits such as the one below:

[image: BQ2057 typical charge circuit]

There is a guide on how to choose that transistor starting on page 15 of the datasheet which shows how to calculate the pass element power dissipation which is the key factor in making the appropriate  choice.

Note that the maximum output current from the CC pin is limited by power dissipation to 40mA.